# Java libmodbus native library unsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, modbus

Hi I am getting the following when I am executing my project jar.

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -jar RDC.jar 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.enfragy.rdc.main.ModbusNativeReader.readInputRegisters(III)[I
        at com.enfragy.rdc.main.ModbusNativeReader.readInputRegisters(Native Method)
        at com.enfragy.rdc.main.ModbusReader.getInputRegisterValue(ModbusReader.java:14)
        at com.enfragy.rdc.main.RdcExecutor.main(RdcExecutor.java:70)
```

The lib is in my path. I have tried with absolute path also but nothing comfort.  But when I am running a small tesing program with same shared library it is running fine. But when I including it with my project it generating exception. I don't know why it behaving strange.

Here is my files

JNI Java Class ::

```
public class ModbusNativeReader {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("adder");
    }
    // A native method that receives nothing and returns void

    public native int[] readInputRegisters(int slaveId, int registerAddr, int registerCount);
}
```

Header file for C code

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_enfragy_rdc_main_ModbusNativeReader */

#ifndef _Included_com_enfragy_rdc_main_ModbusNativeReader
#define _Included_com_enfragy_rdc_main_ModbusNativeReader
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_enfragy_rdc_main_ModbusNativeReader
 * Method:    readInputRegisters
 * Signature: (III)[I
 */
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_enfragy_rdc_main_ModbusNativeReader_readInputRegisters
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Native C Code

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_enfragy_rdc_main_ModbusNativeReader_readInputRegisters
 (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jint slaveId, jint registerAddr, jint registerCount) 
{

jintArray result;
modbus_t *ctx;
uint16_t tab_reg[10];
int rc;
int i;


result = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, 2);
if (result == NULL) {
return NULL; /* out of memory error thrown */
}

...
...


(*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, result, 0, 2, pointer);
return result;
}
```

I don't got the strange behaviour. Can anyone guide me to resolve my issue??

Thank you

Comment: Use [depends.exe](http://dependencywalker.com) or [nm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) to display the actual symbols in your library to ensure that your native method is actually exported from your shared library.

Comment: thank you for help. My method signature was not correct.